# Premium plan for Pusher apps

Tags: pusher

I've seen premium package allows maximum 10 000 connections. So I was wondering what if I have 100 000 or more active users daily, does that mean that I cannot use this plan? If this is true, what are my alternatives.

I know I could of course use Node.js and VPS but I was wondering if Pusher can handle so many users/connections. Maybe my expanses would be less with Pusher.

Answer (score 0):

The connections are maximum concurrent connections. So, if you have 100k active users spread throughout the day but never go over the 10k concurrent connections (number of connections at any one given time) then the 10k plan will be fine for your use case.